# Cursor flash: Backspace-issue in Terminal Vim

Tags: vim, terminal, macvim

**Note**:
This is a plugin-induced problem, but it happens with multiple plugins and it does not happen in MacVim.

**Problem**:
When hitting Backspace in Insert mode while using a plugin which handles automatic closing of brackets, quotes and such ([delimitMate](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate), [vim-autoclose](https://github.com/Townk/vim-autoclose)), the cursor turns into a block while deleting the character (this happens faster than I can blink my eyes but remains one of my pet peeves on terminal Vim), giving the impression of a tiny flash, which on every deletion of a character becomes annoying.

I presume it leaves Insert-mode to perform an normal/ex command), due to the remap done by the plugins, and I can confirm that this "changes to block and back"-flash does NOT happen with the plugins disabled.

The mapping for each of the plugins is as follows:

**delimitMate**
`:verbose imap <BS>` => `i  <BS>   @<Plug>delimitMateBS`
**vim-autoclose**:
`:verbose imap <BS>` =>  `i  <BS>   *@<C-R>=<SNR>44_Backspace()<CR>`

This problably means nothing as I'm not posting what the invoked functions actually do, it's just meant to show that <kbd>Backspace</kbd> is being remapped.

You're probably eager to point me to the issue tracker of each specific plugin at this point, but like mentioned earlier, this issue does **not** happen in MacVim. Perhaps it does, perhaps it's simply happening too fast for my eyes to see, but while using MacVim, there is absolutely no visible cursor change/flash.

Comment: Both plugins have the same purpose but probably different ways to go about it. You could start by making up your mind and choosing one *or* the other, then inspecting the plugin's source to see what it does.

Comment: So, to be clear, you have different cursor shapes for insert and normal mode? (And not in MacVim?) That would explain the behavior (as the plugins have to switch modes to do their stuff).

Comment: I have a vertical line for Insert Mode and block for Normal Mode, both   in terminal and gui Vim, but it's only in the terminal version it flashes.

Comment: Did you achieve the cursor shape change by setting `&t_SI` and `&t_EI` in .vimrc? If so, perhaps you could modify the plugins' autocommands to first set those to empty strings before running their commands; and then restore them to the appropriate terminal escape sequences afterward.

Comment: What did you end up doing here?  Would love an answer or to know if the above suggestion works.